# How to update existing hstore values (and add if it's missing) from other hstore?

Tags: postgresql

I have `hstore` record in database something like

```
"BaseCount"=>"6", "EgaisCount"=>"0", "MarkingCount"=>"1", "MercuryCount"=>"2", "gis_work_mod"=>"1", "other"=>"3"
```

I recalculated the values of this `hstore` for example

```
"BaseCount"=>"6", "EgaisCount"=>"2"
```

Now I want to select existing value ( `"BaseCount"=>"6", "EgaisCount"=>"0", "MarkingCount"=>"1", "MercuryCount"=>"2", "gis_work_mod"=>"1", "other"=>"3"` ) and update keys that only mathes keys from recalculated one ( `"BaseCount"=>"6", "EgaisCount"=>"2"` )

The result should look like

```
"BaseCount"=>"12", "EgaisCount"=>"2", "MarkingCount"=>"1", "MercuryCount"=>"2", "gis_work_mod"=>"1", "other"=>"3". Mathes keys updated, other - not
```

If new keys present - they should be added to result.
For example, if the `hstore` looks like

```
"BaseCount"=>"6", "EgaisCount"=>"2", "NewCounts"=>"5"
```

The result should be

```
 "BaseCount"=>"12", "EgaisCount"=>"2", "MarkingCount"=>"1", "MercuryCount"=>"2", "gis_work_mod"=>"1", "other"=>"3", "NewCounts" =>"5"
```

I tried the `hstore` concatenation - it solves the new value adding but not value updating case

Answer (score 0):

Basic concatenation (`||`) operator solved my problem. My case was that I was concatenating `hstore` and `string`. That was the reason of unexpected behavior.